# How to read this matrix notation

Tags: matrices

Excuse me for this basic question, but when reading some mathematic books I have encountered the following matrix:

```
W = 2diag([1 1 0,01])
```

Could anybody explain to me how can I read this? Is it just a diagonal matrix multiplied by 2?

Comment: In which book have you read?

Comment: Actually it is PhD thesis of one of my lecturers (unfortunatelly not in English) and I am wondering what did he think about writing matrix this way.

Comment: I am not sure, he may mean decimal by , this.

Comment: Yup, sometimes I forget than in my country we use `,` instead of `.`, it's sick :(.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess would be $\texttt{2diag([1 1 0,01])}=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0,02  \end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: Presumably the comma is then a decimal separator?

Comment: @Théophile, Yes.

Comment: I thought that it was more matlab-like style to separate rows, but you kind of opened my eyes. Thank you!

Comment: Ahhhh!  The different radix fooled me.

Comment: I was thinking "second diagonal", perhaps the antidiagonal or the diagonal right above or below the main diagonal.

Comment: @DavidZ your edit has broken the spaces in the formula.

Comment: @Ruslan ah, I missed that... it's odd because for some reason the `\texttt` didn't work on the computer where I submitted the edit, but on the computer I'm on now, it does work. I guess some sort of MathJax caching issue is at fault? Anyway probably the best solution is for someone to roll back my edit. (I can't)

Answer (score 4):

The most reliable way could be to ask your lecturer, otherwise there could be a missing or extra multiplication by $2$.

The line

```
W = 2diag([1 1 0,01])
```

in the question has been typeset as it could be a code from the program. It is not clear whether this is deliberate or occasional, and whether this is exactly how it looks like in the thesis. Moreover, `[]`-brackets inside `()`-brackets strengthen the conjecture that it could be a code from the program. It seems quite viable that the program has a function `2diag` (using a naming convention to put `2` instead of `to`) that takes a list (cf. `[...]` syntax) and creates a corresponding diagonal matrix of an appropriate dimension. This way, `2diag([1 1 0,01])` will create $3x3$ matrix with $1$, $1$ and $0,01$ on its main diagonal. However, if this notation actually means $$2\,\times\,\text{diag}\{1,1,0.01\}$$ then the diagonal of the resulting matrix will be $2$, $2$ and $0,02$. That's why one should be careful.

Comment: There are languages where a number followed by identifier is parsed as number multiplied by that identifier, e.g. in Mathematica `2a` would be equivalent to `2*a`.

Comment: @Ruslan - thanks! This remark shows that there could be even more confusion if the formula is taken out of context. As for Mathematica, I presume in this case the 1st character of the identifier can not be a digit?

Comment: Yes, a digit can't start identifier name. Frankly, I don't even know what languages do allow this.

Comment: @Ruslan: for example, in GAP, an identifier may contain letters, digits, symbols `_` and `@`, and must contain at least one non-digit, but the position of that is not specified; thus, `100x` is a valid identifier in GAP - [see here](http://gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap4.html#X860313A179A5163F)